# How do I troubleshoot problems with this MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj3Jr.png]

I use the command dis ql(WY) and see CURDEPTH is full, what should I do about it

Comment: Instead of posting a screen shot of the text output of the MQSC command, instead just copy and paste the text into the question,  you can go back and click edit to do this.   On the line before and after place three ``` characters, this will make it format just as you have pasted it.

Comment: Please add the output of this command `DIS QS(WY) MONITOR`

Answer (score 1):

Queue is full because there is no application consuming messages from it. You can

1. Identify the application putting messages into this queue and determine if the messages were indented for this queue.
2. If the messages were meant for this queue, was there any application configured to consume messages from this queue? If there was one, is the application running, if it is running why is it not consuming? if not why it is not running, start it.
3. Clear the queue if you think messages are not important. Disable message put to this queue.

**Edit:**

Your screenshot shows IPPROCS(10) and OPPROCS(1) which means the queue is opened by 10 applications for GETting and 1 application for PUTting messages. But still the queue is full. It may be that application is not consuming messages but application is not reporting errors properly.

You can look at last message get date and time statistics on the queue using the DISPLAY QSTATUS command. Look [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=attributes-queue-status) for details.

Comment: thanks your answer Shashi，I have an application that is consuming this queue, and the application log is not reporting any error. I can't pinpoint what's causing the queue to be almost full all the time, although occasionally it will consume to a state of near-fullness,like 49995 .I don't know much about IBM MQ and where I can see its rate of consumption

Comment: See my update above.